# jQuery click function only works the first time on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, animation, mobile, onclick, jquery-animate

The *slideInDown* animation only works the first time (first click/touch) on mobile devices. If I double-tap the burger-icon-menu the animation is working again..

What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.mobile-nav-toggle').on('click touchstart', function(){
  var status = $(this).hasClass('is-o');
  if(status){
    $('.mobile-nav-toggle, .mobile-nav').removeClass('is-o');
    $('#m-nav ul').removeClass('animated slideInDown');
  }else{
    $('.mobile-nav-toggle, .mobile-nav').addClass('is-o');
    $('#m-nav ul').addClass('animated slideInDown');
  }
});
```

Comment: What's the "burger-menu"?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/threelines.png :D

Comment: Darn, I was thinking of the tasty burgers XD

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it, i guess, the issue is due to the order of events firing.

Try this:

```
$( function () {
  $( document ).on( "vmousedown", ".mobile-nav-toggle", function() {
        var status = $(this).hasClass('is-o');
      if(status){
        $('.mobile-nav-toggle, .mobile-nav').removeClass('is-o');
        $('#m-nav ul').removeClass('animated slideInDown');
      }else{
        $('.mobile-nav-toggle, .mobile-nav').addClass('is-o');
        $('#m-nav ul').addClass('animated slideInDown');
      }
  });
});
```